# Match multiple conditions?

Tags: java, regex

What I am trying to do is, if I have a text like this: "this is an example 23*45 and 34". I want to get "23*45" and "34". I have no problem finding ether "23*45" or "34" but having problem getting both of them at the same time..
This is what I got now:

```
"(-?)([0-9]+)\*(-?)([0-9]+)"
```

Comment: make the multiplication part optional:  `\d+(\*\d+)?`

Comment: Just make the * optional: (-?)([0-9]+)\*?(-?)([0-9]+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get "23*45" and "34", you might use:

[`\d+(?:\*\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/rjU3M0/1)

**Explanation**

- Match one or more digits `\d+`
- A non capturing group `(?:`

  - Which will match an asterix and one or more digits`\*\d+`
- close non capturing group `)`
- Make the non capturing group optional `?`

Comment: Nice! Ty! So just if I understand the part added, the "?: *regex code* ?" is the "optional" part? Edit: Saw you updated, ty! :)

Comment: @Salviati I have updated my answer and added some more explanation. `(?:` Makes it a non capturing group. The `)?` makes the non capturing group optional. This might be a helpful page about [optional items](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)